# How to move the jQueryUI close button on the dialog over the top of top right corner?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQueryUI and have a modal dialog setup. The designer wants the close button to look like this:

[image]

I currently have it set up like this:

[image]

The icon is not quite right, ignore that, I do however want to move it up into that top right corner. I thought I could accomplish it with the following CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  border-radius: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: -10px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -18px;
  top: -24%;
  width: 33px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

However now it looks like this:

[image] [image]

How do I get it on top of the dialog? I already have a big z-index on it which doesn't work.

Thankyou.

Comment: It's not the z-index, it's that its container is clipping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set class ui-dialog css property overflow as visilble. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the different value of `border-radius` and `height` value. 
it could be the reason border-radius value is just half of the height. so change the `height` value.

For example

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  border-radius: 17px;
  height: 50px; /*change from 33 to 50px*/
  margin: -10px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -18px;
  top: -24%;
  width: 33px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: just curious, by making the value changes in height or radius make any impact?